# Windows batch file: how to enable inline echo of a command

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

If echo is disabled by default within a Windows batch file, is there a way to enable it "inline" for a specific command? I know that echoing of a specific command can be **disabled** by prepending "@" to the command, but is there a way to do the opposite of this?

For example, suppose a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
:EOF
```

How could I force echo'ing of, say, cmd2 above?

Comment: Simply double the command with an echo in front.

Comment: No, there is no character with the reverse function of `@`, you can only use `echo on` and `echo off` as needed; also if `cmd?` are batch files on their on (which you'd need to precede them with `call`) and they enable/disable command echoes on their own, you cannot override the bahaviour in your main batch file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply start your batch `cmd2` by `@echo on` and end by `@echo off`?

Comment: That's the default solution, but I was wondering if there was something a little more clever.